# TWinSocketStream.WaitForData how does it know if I am intending to read or to write?

Tags: delphi, network-programming

I am creating a TCP client/server using TClientSocket/TServerSocket in blocking mode. A proof of concept Server is already built and tested for basic functionality (to receive data) using telnet. On the client, there will be two threads one for writing and the other for reading. Now, to test the "Send (or write) thread" I am using the following code. But stream.WaitForData(30000) always times out. Delphi help says "**Call WaitForData before reading or writing information over the socket connection**". So I am wondering how does the TWinSockStream know that I am calling WaitForData for writing and not for reading?

```
procedure TClientThread.Execute;
var
  stream: TWinSocketStream;
  buffer: string;
begin

  stream := TWinSocketStream.Create(FClientSocket.Socket, 60000);
  try
    while (not Terminated) and (FClientSocket.Active) do
    begin
      try
        //FSendDataEvent is a trigger used for testing purpose
        if FSendDataEvent.WaitFor(1000) = wrSignaled then
        begin
          FSendDataEvent.ResetEvent;

          if stream.WaitForData(30000) then
          begin
            buffer := 'Hello from client';
            stream.Write(buffer, Length(buffer) + 1 );
          end;
        end;
        //Other useful code
      except
        on E:Exception do
        begin
          DebugOutput('TClientThread.Execute: ' + E.Message);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    stream.free;
  end;

end;
```

Even if WaitForData() is removed, the text is not transmitted to the Server as it is. But the following code works fine when called directly -- with no WaitForData().

```
FClientSocket.Socket.SendText('Hi from client');
```

So what is the correct way of using TWinSocketStream with TClientSocket?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. `WaitForData()` only works for reading, not for writing.

As for writing data with `TWinSocketStream`, you are passing the wrong value in the first parameter of `Write()`, that is why it does not send correctly. The first parameter is an untyped `const`, so you need to deference the string in order to pass the memory address of the first character, eg:

```
Stream.Write(Buffer[1], ...);
```

Or:

```
Stream.Write(PChar(Buffer)^, ...);
```

Comment: Aha! I see the error now! Interestingly the code is based on a snippet from _"Delphi 5 Developer's Guide" - Chapter 30 Working with sockets_. I will make appropriate changes and post back the result. Thank you.